# I need random algorithm with weighing options

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, random

I have a requirement in my .NET project where I need to select an item from a collection, each item has a Weight (integer from 1 to 10) assigned to it.

I need a random generator that would take this weight into consideration i.e., the higher the weight, the more chances the object would be selected.

Quick copy/paste C# code in case someone stumbles upon this.

```
    class RandomWeightedSelector<T>
    {
        private List<T> items = new List<T>();

        public void Add(T item, uint weight = 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < weight; i++)
                items.Add(item);
        }

        public T GetRandom()
        {
            return items[new Random().Next(0, items.Count)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not want to be creating a new random every call to `GetRandom`.  The default constructor for `Random` seeds the generator with the system uptime in milliseconds.  If you call your `GetRandom` more than once a millisecond, you will be returned the same value.  Even if you don't, you could be returning results which have worse 'randomness' than just reusing a single `Random` instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an algorithm which doesn't require adding the items multiple times to a list. It can also work with non-integer weights, although if you're using NextDouble from System.Random, you'll have to scale all of the weights to add up to 1, or multiply the value from NextDouble with S to get it in the desired range.

Given a list L of items (I,W), where I is the item and W is the weight:

1. Add all of the weights together. Call this sum S.
2. Generate a random number between 0 and S (excluding S, but including 0). Call this value R.
3. Initialize a variable to 0 to keep track of the running total. We'll call this T.
4. For each item (I,W) in L:

   1. T=T+W
   2. If T > R, return I.

Comment: Instead of scaling your weights, you could just use `NextDouble()*S`

Comment: @Justin: Yes, that would also work. I've updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Make a list and insert each item in Weight number of times. Then choose a random item from the list.

Comment: It should be noted that this works because your weights are always going to be integers.

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement. Weight will always be integer and at least 1. Upper weight bound is not important it seems.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called the Weighted Selector algorithm. I actually created an open source C# project for this some time ago!

It's very easy to use and efficient. Also, the documentation should get you going with no problem.

Here are a few links:

- [Weighted Selector on Github](https://github.com/kinetiq/Ether.WeightedSelector)
- [Weighted Selector nuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ether.WeightedSelector/)